# Jquery - For each wait show modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm testing to create a each loop with an array object. I would like to every element show a modal window with a data and with a question. After response the question the modal hide and show with other array element.

I have read a lot of information and the each loop cann't wait response¿?

Modal:

[image]

This interface use to ask user to replace an image.

I'm working in this code:

```
$.each( arrayExist, function( i, value ) {

     if (value == 1) {                                     // Show modal with the old and new image when value is true

           alert ('Exist');

           $('#overwriteImages').modal('show');

           $('#overwriteImages').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

              $('input[type="submit"]').click(function(event){

                  $('#btnYes').on('click', function() {
                      $('#overwriteImages').modal('hide');
                  });

                  $('#btnNo').on('click', function() {
                      $('#overwriteImages').modal('hide');

                      arrayCod.splice( $.inArray(removeItem,i) ,1 );

                      alert(arrayCod.length);
                  });

               });

           });
           }else{
               alert ('Not Exist');
           }

     });
```

I'm not sure that is possible to do it or it would be a better option... ajax or whatever.

The problem is that the each loop is execute in each modal window. It doesn't wait to response Yes or No. Example:

Select two elements.

Element(1) -> Show Modal and two alerts because the each loop running at two times)

Element(2) -> Show Modal and two alerts because the each loop running at two times)

The correct behaviur would be:

Select two elements.

Element(1) -> Show Modal and an alert only with this element.

Element(2) -> Show Modal and an alert only with this element.

**The summary is:** I need that the each loop wait to response in modal window to be continue the loop.

Comment: It's not quite clear what the problem is, but from the title, try changing `show.bs.modal` to `shown.bs.modal` as this is only triggered after any transitions on the modal have completed

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have edited with more details. I need that the each loop wait to response in modal window to be continue the loop.

Comment: And... you should **never** nest event handler bindings in each other. In your code you have nested them 3 levels deep: big no no.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a loop here. Of course, the `each` function won't wait to return from a "modal" window, because your window isn't modal actually (only `alert`, `prompt` and `comfirm` are authentic modals). Everything goes through events, so declare a variable that holds de index of the element you want to show now, and increment and decrement it as the user clicks "nueva" or "anterior" recovering the element from the array and operating with it.